# Is there any way to track user usage of my app in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I had developed an android app (no ios version) in flutter and my app is almost ready but there is one missing thing that I have to give user points or any mark like levels (silver, gold, platinium, etc) in order to give them some benefits.

How can I do that? Is there a package that could help me with my needs? I have tried to calculate time the user has spent on my app, sending it to server, but the code did not work. If any code can calculate the time correctly it will also be of help.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at Firebase/Google Analytics and how you can monitor user metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having in mind you've put in the firebase tag in the title, I'd assume your backend is on it.

With it, you can deploy the Firebase Analytics, in combination with Firebase Cloud Firestore and Cloud Functions in order to create a system that rewards users based on their engagement or other metrics, allowing levels like silver, gold, platinum.

The way it happens is:

1. In Firebase Analytics, you track user behaviour and engagement in the app, there are in built functions that allow to track the time a user spends inside of the app, purchases items and anything else you might need.
2. With Firestore you are going to store user profiles and the points collected based on levels, much as a database.
3. With the Cloud Functions you are going to create events, such as that update user points and levels in the DB based on the analytics data.

if you've already added Firebase Analytics and Cloud Firestore to your dependencies and configured it, you'd only need to create the Firebase Cloud Functions. Use the Firebase CLI to generate them, and after that write whatever you need in the provided JS file.

An example function may look like that:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.updateUserPoints = functions.analytics.event('event_name').onLog((event) => {
  const userId = event.user.userId; // Assuming you're setting user ID in analytics
  const userRef = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId);

  // Calculate points based on the event (customize as needed)
  const pointsToAdd = 100;

  return userRef.update({
    points: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(pointsToAdd)
  });
});
```

Comment: any references please?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely:
1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=android
2. https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/user-properties?platform=android#java
3. https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews